# Async WFC server side like IHttpAsyncHandler

Tags: wcf, asynchronous

I'd like to be able to create a WCF service that the client see as synchronous, but is implemented server side as asynchronous. I know that ASP.NET allows me to do this by implementing the IHttpAsyncHandler, but can't seem to find the equivalent in WCF.

This is a service that exists already and we'd like to move over to an asynchronous implement server side, without changing the client. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on .Net 4.5 change the OperationContract methods in service contract interface to return `Task<type>` instead of type. In the class that implements the interface use the async modifier on the methods and use await inside following the Task based Asynchronous Pattern
See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734701
http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2012/DEV326

Comment: We're not yet on .NET 4.5, we could upgrade the server no problem, but upgrading the clients would be more complex. Isn't there anyway to do it without changing the contract?

Comment: If you upgrade the service to WCF 4.5 the contract will remain the same even if you return Task<type> instead of type. The example has generating client proxy that also has Task<type> but this is optional. The client will generate non-async methods if they are on lower version.

Comment: +1. WCF metadata always describes the interface as synchronous, so it should be no problem to have an asynchronous WCF implementation that appears synchronous to the clients. See my blog post [Async WCF Today and Tomorrow](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/08/async-wcf-today-and-tomorrow.html) for details on `async` WCF on both .NET 4.0 and 4.5.